# iOS: how to point to particular control on UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've placed UISwitch, UILabel and couple of buttons on UITableViewCell and now now I need them to react properly (show/hide) when UISwitch changes status.

My problem is that the over mentioned UILabel and buttons they are hiding and originating on random cells, not in this particular one where the UISwitch is placed.

I went so far:

```
-(void)hideQualityBtn:(id)sender
{
if(sender.tag==9001)
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=((UITableViewCell*)[sender superview]);
   // cell.control.....hidden=YES;
}
}
```

Help is much appreciated, thank you in advance.

EDIT:

in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
self.switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 8, 79, 27)];
[switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(setItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[switchView setTag:9001];
[cell addSubview:switchView];
[cell setIndentationWidth:45];
[cell setIndentationLevel:1];
```

setItem meth:

```
-(void)setItem:(UISwitch*)sender
{
int n;
UITableViewCell *cell;
// so i'm getting item ID
if(sender.tag==9001)
{
    cell=((UITableViewCell*)[sender superview]);
    n=([self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell].row);
}
item=[self.arr objectAtIndex:n];

NSDate *today=[NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString *now =[formatter stringFromDate:today];

if(sender.on)
{
    DBAccess *access=[[DBAccess alloc]init];
    [access setItemON:item.itemID date:now];
    qualityBtn.hidden=NO;
    [qualityBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:normal];
    [qualityBtn setTitle:@"UNDEF" forState:normal];
}
else 
{
    DBAccess *access=[[DBAccess alloc]init];
    [access setItemOFF:item.itemID];
}
}
```

My particular question is how to point to control that located in particular cell?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the UITableViewCell in your implementation of tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath: and keep a reference (probably in a property) to your UISwitch so that you can access it when interesting events happen.